# With Nock, can you match any domain?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nock

I have got this unit test code which mocks an HTTP request:

```
nock(/localhost/)
  .post(/validate-user$/, credentials)
  .reply(401);
```

This works fine. However, I don't really care about the domain. In fact, the domain will change. This will break my unit tests.

Can I specify a wildcard domain for Nock?

I've tried `nock(/.*/)` but it does not work.

The Nock recorder outputs:

```
<<<<<<-- cut here -->>>>>>

nock('https://localhost:41109', {"encodedQueryParams":true})
  .post('/mock-validate-user', {"username":"alexxx","password":"alexxx100"})
  .reply(200, {"username":"alexxx","email":"alexxx@foo.com","admin":true}, 
  [ 'Content-Type',
  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'Content-Length',
  '59',
  'ETag',
  'W/"3b-JaaJntKHf2/nzwhkqdNoFA"',
  'Date',
  'Thu, 02 Mar 2017 16:11:06 GMT',
  'Connection',
  'close' ]);

<<<<<<-- cut here -->>>>>>
```

Comment: `nock(/.*/)` should work. Have you got an example of the URL you're wanting `nock` to capture?

Comment: ive added the nock recorder output - yes i do have the nock recorder turned off normally